# Using functions in the same namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

Have a query on function using function in the same namespace. How do I call the function? It seems to keep on giving me error.

#### E.g:

```
// in the .h files
namespace helper{ 
    void helper1();
    void helper2();
}

// in the cpp files
namespace helper{
    void helper1() { 
      // blah blah blah
    }

    void helper2() {
      // blah blah blah
      helper1();    // return some results from helper1
    }
}
```

The above code gives me error result, saying it can't find the `helper1` function. Is there anything I have done wrongly?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/SYnhOO). The problem must be in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: strange but it says it cant find the helper function. Perhaps I would try again

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are asking the right quesiton? This is what I have, and it works fine:

```
// this is helper.cpp
#include<iostream>

#include "helper.hpp"

namespace helper{
void helper1() { 
  std::cout<<"calling helper 1"<<std::endl;
}

void helper2() {
  std::cout<<"calling helper 2"<<std::endl;
  helper1(); 
}
}

int main() {
  helper::helper2();
  return 0;
}
```

and the header file

```
//this is helper.hpp
namespace helper{ 
void helper1();
void helper2();
}
```

compiled using

```
g++ helper.cpp -ansi -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
```

returns no warnings and yields

```
$ ./a.out
calling helper 2
calling helper 1
```

Comment: perhaps I would try again